# Issues with extra MIDI track being created in AKsequencer, using audiokit

Tags: ios, swift, audio, midi, audiokit

I've been trying to solve a mystery [sinewave issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160168/trying-to-debug-mystery-sinewave-using-akmidisampler-in-audiokit) with little success. I'm starting a new question here as I think I have dug into the specifics of this problem.

When setting up an AKSequencer, and feeding it a MIDI file, I'm seeing some strange results.

For a 4 track song (with a corresponding 4 track midi file, duration matching all stems of the song), I'm seeing that the sequencer is actually generated with 5 tracks. What is the extra track?

Also, I'm getting an error in the console:

`[seq] 1026: Invalid beat range`

which I believe happens when the track is empty.

So this looks like the culprit for my mystery sinewave.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? It's been driving me a little crazy...

Thanks!

Comment: Tempo changes must be in a single track, so most sequencers generate a separate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe CL is correct that the extra track is a midi track. Usually a sine wave means that you're not connected to anything else to generate the sounds, so the sequencer lets you know this by using the sine wave (wouldn't have been my first choice, but thats an internal Apple decision).

Comment: Thanks Aure, your input was also part of my finding a workaround to this issue... (Shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160168/trying-to-debug-mystery-sinewave-using-akmidisampler-in-audiokit) 